# Setting alternating classes in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I have a table with the rows populated by Angular.

I'm wondering if there is a "better" way of specifying the class for each row than in the javascript dataset? The classes tr1 and tr2 set an alternating background color for the table rows.

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="store">
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    (function() {
        var app = angular.module('store', []);

        app.controller('storeController', function() {
            this.gems = dataArray;
        });

        var dataArray = [{
                name: 'diamond',
                trClass: 'tr1',
            }, {
                name: 'ruby',
                trClass: 'tr2',
            }, {
                name: 'sapphire',
                trClass: 'tr1',
            }, {
                name: 'emerald',
                trClass: 'tr2',
            }];
        })();

    </script>

    <style>
        .tr1 {
            background-color: yellow;
        }
        .tr2 {
        background-color: white;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body ng-controller="storeController as products">


<table border="1">
    <tr ng-repeat="gem in products.gems" class="{{ gem.trClass }}">
        <td>{{gem.name}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `ng-class-odd` and `ng-class-even` to alternately apply your classes.

Answer (score 0):

Yo can change class like as-

```
<table border="1">
    <tr ng-repeat="gem in products.gems" ng-class="{$index%2==0?'tr2':'tr1'}">
        <td>{{gem.name}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm gonna go with @Lex `<tr ng-repeat="gem in products.gems" ng-class-odd="'tr1'" ng-class-even="'tr2'">`